# Tableau: time difference excluding weekends, outside business hours, and holidays

Tags: sql, date, tableau-api

I'm working in Tableau. I have two timestamps and would like to find the DD:HH:MM:SS difference between them excluding weekends, outside business hours, *and holidays*. I've found a number of solutions that address excluding weekends and outside business hours, but so far nothing addressing the issue with holidays. Is this possible? If not, do I need to do the calculation in my custom SQL using some sort of holiday lookup table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer to my own question. It does require the use of a holiday table or some sort of calendar table where your holidays are defined. This could be Excel, SQL, whatever. You will probably need to modify the join conditions below to fit the specifics of your table.

Example custom SQL queries that I used. `DESCRIPTION` refers to the name of the holiday ("Christmas", "Christmas Eve", etc)

`custom_sql1`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CALENDAR_YEAR,
        DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION_ASSIGNED,
        HOLIDAY_DATE AS HOLIDAY_DATE_ASSIGNED
FROM YOUR_HOLIDAY_TABLE
```

`custom_sql2`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CALENDAR_YEAR,
        DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION_CREATED,
        HOLIDAY_DATE AS HOLIDAY_DATE_CREATED
FROM YOUR_HOLIDAY_TABLE
```

Once you have that, then you can start.

This example has two dates: the time a case was created (`created_ts`) and the time it was assigned (`assigned_ts`).

### **(1) TABLE JOINS**

Left join your holiday/calendar table twice to your main table, once for each timestamp. In the example below `custom_sql_query` is my main table, and `custom_sql_query1` and `custom_sql_query2` are my holiday tables.

[image: Screenshot illustrating table joins]

`custom_sql_query1`:

CUSTOM JOIN CONDITION FOR MAIN TABLE:

*Note: This assumes that the end of your workday is at 8:00pm (20:00). Adjust the "19" accordingly.*

```
IF      DATENAME('weekday',[assigned_ts]) = 'Friday'
        AND DATEPART('hour',[assigned_ts]) > 19
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',3,[assigned_ts]))

ELSEIF       DATENAME('weekday',[assigned_ts]) = 'Saturday'
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',2,[assigned_ts]))

ELSEIF       DATENAME('weekday',[assigned_ts]) = 'Sunday'
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',1,[assigned_ts]))

ELSEIF   DATEPART('hour',[assigned_ts]) > 19
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',1,[assigned_ts]))

ELSE  DATETRUNC('day',[assigned_ts])
END
```

CUSTOM JOIN CONDITION FOR HOLIDAY TABLE: `DATETRUNC('day',[HOLIDAY_DATE_ASSIGNED])`

---

`custom_sql_query2`:

CUSTOM JOIN CONDITION FOR MAIN TABLE:

*Note: This assumes that the end of your workday is at 8:00pm (20:00). Adjust the "19" accordingly.*

```
IF      DATENAME('weekday',[created_ts]) = 'Friday'
        AND DATEPART('hour',[created_ts]) > 19
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',3,[created_ts]))

ELSEIF       DATENAME('weekday',[created_ts]) = 'Saturday'
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',2,[created_ts]))

ELSEIF       DATENAME('weekday',[created_ts]) = 'Sunday'
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',1,[created_ts]))

ELSEIF   DATEPART('hour',[created_ts]) > 19
    THEN DATETRUNC('day',DATEADD('day',1,[created_ts]))

ELSE  DATETRUNC('day',[created_ts])
END
```

CUSTOM JOIN CONDITION FOR HOLIDAY TABLE: `DATETRUNC('day',[HOLIDAY_DATE_CREATED])`

### **(2) CREATE PARAMETERS**

Create parameters that define the day and minute your workday starts and ends. Example `Day Open Hour` and `Day Open Minute` parameters are below. `Day Close Hour` and `Day Close Minute` would be created exactly the same way, except you'd change the "Current Value" option to whatever corresponded to the end hour/minute of your business day:

```
[Day Open Hour]
Name: Day Open Hour
Data Type: Integer
Current Value: 8 (assumes workday starts at 8:00am)
Display format: Automatic
Allowable Values: Range
Range of values: Min = 0, Max = 23, Step = 1

[Day Open Minute]
Name: Day Open Minute
Data type: String
Current value: 00
Allowable values: List
List of values:
Value - Display As
0       00
30      30

(change minute increments as needed)
```

### **(3) PUSH YOUR TIMESTAMPS: NEXT DAY**

Create calculated fields

If something was assigned/created outside of business hours this rounds to the business start of the next day. Note that we're not excluding weekends or holidays yet.

`assigned_ts: next day`:

```
IF (DATEPART('hour', [assigned_ts]) * 60) + DATEPART('minute', [assigned_ts])  
        > (60 * ([Day Close Hour]) ) + INT([Day Close Minute])
THEN
// created after End of Day so round to start of next business day
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (24 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute]), 
        DATETRUNC('day',[assigned_ts])) 
ELSEIF
(DATEPART('hour', [assigned_ts]) * 60) + DATEPART('minute', [assigned_ts])  
        < (60 * [Day Open Hour]) + INT([Day Open Minute])
THEN
// created before Start of Day so round to start of business day
DATEADD('minute', (60 * [Day Open Hour]) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day',[assigned_ts])) 
ELSE
[assigned_ts]
END
```

`created_ts: next day`:

```
IF (DATEPART('hour', [created_ts]) * 60) + DATEPART('minute', [created_ts])  
        > (60 * ([Day Close Hour]) ) + INT([Day Close Minute])
THEN
// created after End of Day so round to start of next business day
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (24 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute]), 
        DATETRUNC('day',[created_ts])) 
ELSEIF
(DATEPART('hour', [created_ts]) * 60) + DATEPART('minute', [created_ts])  
        < (60 * [Day Open Hour]) + INT([Day Open Minute])
THEN
// created before Start of Day so round to start of business day
DATEADD('minute', (60 * [Day Open Hour]) + INT([Day Open Minute]), DATETRUNC('day',[created_ts])) 
ELSE
[created_ts]
END
```

### **(4) PUSH YOUR TIMESTAMPS: EXCLUDE WEEKENDS**

If your "rounded" timestamps above fall on a weekend, this pushes them to the next Monday. Create another two calculated fields:

`assigned_ts: next weekday`:

```
IF DATENAME('weekday',[assigned_ts: next day]) = "Saturday" 
THEN 
// move to start of day Monday by adding two days (48 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (48 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [assigned_ts: next day]))
ELSEIF DATENAME('weekday',[assigned_ts: next day]) = "Sunday" 
THEN
// move to start of day Monday by adding a day (24 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (24 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [assigned_ts: next day]))
ELSE 
[assigned_ts: next day]
END
```

`created_ts: next weekday`:

```
IF DATENAME('weekday',[created_ts: next day]) = "Saturday" 
THEN 
// move to start of day Monday by adding two days (48 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (48 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [created_ts: next day]))
ELSEIF DATENAME('weekday',[created_ts: next day]) = "Sunday" 
THEN
// move to start of day Monday by adding a day (24 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (24 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [created_ts: next day]))
ELSE 
[created_ts: next day]
END
```

### **(5) PUSH YOUR TIMESTAMPS: EXCLUDE HOLIDAYS**

You first pushed your timestamp to the next day if the timestamp was outside business hours. Then you pushed it further to a Monday if it fell on a weekend after the first push. Now you push it a third time if it falls on a holiday. Note we account for holidays that fall on Fridays. Create yet another two calculated fields.

The first condition in these calculations assume you're getting the day after Thanksgiving off.

`assigned_final`:

```
IF      ([DESCRIPTION_ASSIGNED] = 'Thanksgiving Day' 
            OR [DESCRIPTION_ASSIGNED]= 'Christmas Eve')
        AND DATENAME('weekday',[assigned_ts: next weekday]) = "Thursday" 
THEN 
// move to start of day Monday by adding 4 days (96 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (96 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [assigned_ts: next weekday]))

ELSEIF  NOT ISNULL([HOLIDAY_DATE_ASSIGNED])
        AND DATENAME('weekday',[assigned_ts: next weekday]) = "Friday" 
THEN
// move to start of day Monday by adding 3 days (72 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (72 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [assigned_ts: next weekday]))

ELSEIF  [DESCRIPTION_ASSIGNED]= 'Christmas Eve'
THEN 
// move to start of next day by adding 2 days (48 hrs) and the morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (48 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [assigned_ts: next weekday]))

ELSEIF  NOT ISNULL([HOLIDAY_DATE_ASSIGNED])
THEN
// move to start of next day by adding 1 day (24 hrs) and the morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (24 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [assigned_ts: next weekday]))

ELSE 
[assigned_ts: next weekday]
END
```

`created_final`:

```
IF      ([DESCRIPTION_CREATED] = 'Thanksgiving Day' 
            OR [DESCRIPTION_CREATED]= 'Christmas Eve')
        AND DATENAME('weekday',[created_ts: next weekday]) = "Thursday" 
THEN 
// move to start of day Monday by adding 4 days (96 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (96 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [created_ts: next weekday]))

ELSEIF  NOT ISNULL([HOLIDAY_DATE_CREATED])
        AND DATENAME('weekday',[created_ts: next weekday]) = "Friday" 
THEN
// move to start of day Monday by adding 3 days (72 hrs) and the Monday morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (72 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [created_ts: next weekday]))

ELSEIF  [DESCRIPTION_CREATED]= 'Christmas Eve'
THEN 
// move to start of next day by adding 2 days (48 hrs) and the morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (48 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [created_ts: next weekday]))

ELSEIF  NOT ISNULL([HOLIDAY_DATE_CREATED])
THEN
// move to start of next day by adding 1 day (24 hrs) and the morning hours
DATEADD('minute', (60 * (24 + [Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day', [created_ts: next weekday]))

ELSE 
[created_ts: next weekday]
END
```

### **(6) INTERMEDIARY CALCULATIONS**

1. Calculate minutes per workday.

`minutes per workday`:

`(60 * ([Day Close Hour] - [Day Open Hour]) + INT([Day Close Minute]) -  INT([Day Open Minute]))`

2. Find number of minutes between the start of the day and the modified assignation timestamp

`assigned_final: time to SOD`:

```
DATEDIFF(  'minute',
    DATEADD('minute', (60 * ([Day Open Hour])) + INT([Day Open Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day',[assigned_final])),
    [assigned_final]
)
```

3. Find number of minutes between the modified creation timestamp and the end of the business day

`created_final: time to EOD`:

```
DATEDIFF(  'minute',
    [created_final], 
    DATEADD('minute', (60 * ([Day Close Hour])) + INT([Day Close Minute])
        , DATETRUNC('day',[created_final]))
)
```

### **(7) TIME DIFFERENCE**

Calculates the time difference in minutes.

`Time to Assign`:

```
IF DATETRUNC('day', [created_final]) = 
        DATETRUNC('day', [assigned_final])
THEN
// the same day so just return the minutes between the two times on the same day
[DateDiff minutes]
ELSEIF DATETRUNC('week', [created_final]) = 
        DATETRUNC('week', [assigned_final])
THEN
// the two days are in the same week, so add the time on the created day, 
// the time on the end day, plus a full day for each day between
(([DateDiff days] - 1) * [minutes per workday] ) + 
        [created_final: time to EOD] + [assigned_final: time from SOD]

ELSE
// the days are in two different weeks, so get the same calc as above, 
// and subtract the weekends between.
// weekends between would be datediff weeks * 2 * work minutes per day
(([DateDiff days] - 1 - ([DateDiff weeks] * 2)) * [minutes per workday] ) + 
        [created_final: time to EOD] + [assigned_final: time from SOD]
END
```

Extremely convoluted but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need something like:

- a holidays for each year table
- a business hours table or hard coded
- you need to worry about either end being inside holidays or other un-times and adjust the parameters inward to an actual-time before subtracting all the un-times between them.
- You also need to guard or accommodate the difference being negative (times in the wrong order).
- Next worry about DST differences between the start and end, maybe another algorithm or, if your epoch includes DST law changes, table.